# PyQt4: QGraphicsItem mousePressEvent() disables flag ItemIsMovable

Tags: mouseevent, pyqt4, qgraphicsitem, mousepress

Here's a bug which I accidently solved it and have no idea why that works. I hope that someone could explain to me the logics behind it.

I've reimplmented QGraphicsItem and its mousePressEvent.
By doing that the item was no longer movable.
Even when trying to call `QGraphicsItem.mousePressEvent(self, event)` it didn't work.
Only when I reimplmented mouseMoveEvent() and mouseReleaseEvent() it finally worked.

Code:

```
class LWResizeableItem(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):

    def __init__(self):

        super(LWResizeableItem, self).__init__()
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        QtGui.QGraphicsItem.mousePressEvent(self, event)
        < some code.... >

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        QtGui.QGraphicsItem.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        QtGui.QGraphicsItem.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)
```

Comment: The [Qt C++ documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#mousePressEvent) explains how Qt decides which item to give mouse events to. Maybe it helps (I'm not 100% sure if it explains what you were seeing, I think it depends on your implementation of `mousePressEvent()`)

Answer (score 1):

> A mouse event is propagated up the parent widget chain until a widget
>   accepts it with accept(), or an event filter consumes it.

My guess, since you did not show relevant code, is that your `mousePressEvent` accepted the event.  That prevented `QtGui` from handling it (Your code did all the handling).

You solved the "bug" by calling `QtGui.QGraphicsItem.mousePressEvent` which performs the default function (in addition to your own).

Adding the other two functions (`mouseMoveEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent`) must have coincided with your adding the

```
QtGui.QGraphicsItem.mousePressEvent(self, event)
```

line to your `mousePressEvent` - that is why it seemed to have solved the problem.