# mousePressEvent disables QGraphicsItem ItemIsMovable

Tags: python, qgraphicsscene, pyside2

I have a situation where I want to draw circles onto an image displayed in a `QGraphicsScene` in a `QGraphicsView` (see screenshot).

[image]

I am currently placing the red circles by overriding the `mousePressEvent` of a custom `QGraphicsScene` object, however this seems to prevent the mouse events from propagating through to the `QGraphicsEllipseItem`s which form the circles. This is a shame, since I would like these to remain movable and selectable. My current hack is to maintain a list of generated `QGraphicsItem`s and simply loop through them, calling their event handler, eg:

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    for circ in self.circs:
        if circ.rect().contains(event.scenePos()) or circ.isSelected():
            circ.mouseMoveEvent(event)
```

This kiiind of works, but seems to be a bit buggy (sometimes ellipses become unselectable). I ought to mention that the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34884188/pyqt4-qgraphicsitem-mousepressevent-disables-flag-itemismovable) does not work for me. If I try to propagate the events using something like `QtGui.QGraphicsItem.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)`, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 58, in mouseMoveEvent
    QtGui.QGraphicsItem.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)
AttributeError: module 'PySide2.QtGui' has no attribute 'QGraphicsItem'
```

So what is the correct and proper way to do this? A code example is below.

main.py:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui

import ui.main_window as main_window
import sys
import data_loader.data_loaders as module_data

import cv2 as cv

img_default_size = (512, 512)


class WingSceneWidget(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)
        self.keypoints = []
        self.annotating = False
        self.p_item = None
        self.circs = []

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        print("New Annotation")
        self.annotating = True
        self.keypoints = []
        for circ in self.circs:
            self.removeItem(circ)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        circ_radius = 5
        if self.annotating:
            x = event.scenePos().x()
            y = event.scenePos().y()
            self.keypoints.append([x, y])
            circ = QGraphicsEllipseItem(x-circ_radius, y-circ_radius, circ_radius*2, circ_radius*2, self.p_item)
            circ.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 2))
            circ.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
            circ.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
            self.circs.append(circ)

            print(self.keypoints)
            if len(self.keypoints) >= 8:
                self.annotating = False

        for circ in self.circs:
            if circ.rect().contains(event.scenePos()):
                circ.mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        for circ in self.circs:
            if circ.rect().contains(event.scenePos()) or circ.isSelected():
                circ.mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        for circ in self.circs:
            if circ.rect().contains(event.scenePos()) or circ.isSelected():
                circ.mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def give_pitem(self, p_item):
        self.p_item = p_item


class WingNet(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, main_window.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.folder_list = []
        self.scene = WingSceneWidget(self.gv_wing_image)
        self.gv_wing_image.setScene(self.scene)
        self.gv_wing_image.setRenderHints(QPainter.Antialiasing | QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform)

        self.btn_label_wings.clicked.connect(self.browse_folders)
        self.listWidget.currentItemChanged.connect(self.selection_changed)

    def browse_folders(self):
        self.listWidget.clear()  # In case there are any existing elements in the list

        file_dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog()
        file_dialog.setFileMode(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DirectoryOnly)
        file_dialog.setOption(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog, True)
        file_view = file_dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QListView, 'listView')

        # to make it possible to select multiple directories:
        if file_view:
            file_view.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        f_tree_view = file_dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QTreeView)
        if f_tree_view:
            f_tree_view.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)

        if file_dialog.exec():
            self.folder_list = file_dialog.selectedFiles()

        if self.folder_list:
            image_paths = module_data.get_image_paths(self.folder_list)
            for image_path in image_paths:
                print(image_path)
                self.listWidget.addItem(image_path)

        self.btn_edit_tps.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_label_wings.setText("Start")
        self.btn_label_wings.clicked.disconnect()

    def selection_changed(self):
        selected = self.listWidget.currentItem().text()
        print(selected)
        image = cv.imread(selected)
        image = cv.resize(image, img_default_size)
        height, width, channel = image.shape
        bytes_per_line = 3 * width
        q_img = QtGui.QImage(image.data, width, height, bytes_per_line, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(q_img)

        p_item = self.scene.addPixmap(pixmap)
        self.scene.give_pitem(p_item)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = WingNet()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

main_window.py:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(803, 616)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.splitter_image_list = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter_image_list.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter_image_list.setObjectName("splitter_image_list")
        self.gv_wing_image = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.splitter_image_list)
        self.gv_wing_image.setObjectName("gv_wing_image")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.splitter_image_list)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.splitter_image_list)
        self.h_layout_buttons = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.h_layout_buttons.setObjectName("h_layout_buttons")
        self.btn_edit_tps = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_edit_tps.setObjectName("btn_edit_tps")
        self.h_layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_edit_tps)
        self.btn_label_wings = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_label_wings.setObjectName("btn_label_wings")
        self.h_layout_buttons.addWidget(self.btn_label_wings)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.h_layout_buttons)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 803, 25))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, -1))
        self.btn_edit_tps.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Edit Existing TPS", None, -1))
        self.btn_label_wings.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Label New Wings", None, -1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're overriding the scene mousePressEvent, you have to check what item exists at the mouse coordinates by yourself; this can be achieved by using `QGraphicsScene.items()`, which returns a list of items at those coordinates, in z-index order (from top to bottom).

In your case, just ensure that some item exists, and that the topmost is a QGraphicsEllipseItem; if that's the case, just proceed with the base class implementation, otherwise add the point. This also means that you don't have to override mouseMoveEvent nor mouseReleaseEvent.

```py
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        items = self.items(event.scenePos())
        if items and isinstance(items[0], QGraphicsEllipseItem):
            QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene.mousePressEvent(self, event)
            return
        if self.annotating:
            circ_radius = 5
            x = event.scenePos().x()
            y = event.scenePos().y()
            self.keypoints.append([x, y])
            circ = QGraphicsEllipseItem(x-circ_radius, y-circ_radius, circ_radius*2, circ_radius*2, self.p_item)
            circ.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 2))
            circ.setFlags(circ.flags() | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

            if len(self.keypoints) >= 8:
                self.annotating = False
```

For future reference, try to provide examples as minimal and reproducible as possible: there was no need for the whole loading mechanism, nor for the cv module dependency.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this works very nicely. Sorry about the excess code, I prefer to err on the side of giving too much rather than too little.

Comment: You're welcome, and don't worry, I can understand your point of view. Just keep in mind that not everybody is eager to help once they find it too hard to just get your code working, even before being able to understand what the actual problem is. Sometimes, "giving too much" (expecially if it doesn't relate to the issue at hand) can be a problem, and you risk that people that could actually help you would give up even before trying, because they might not have enough time to sort out how make your code run at first.